# sk_data_ready callback not able to get fragment data

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver

sk_data_ready callback is given with function. processing skb by acquiring read_lock(&sk->sk_callback_lock). skb->data_len shows fragment size. but when we deference skb shared info structure shinfo = skb_shinfo(skb), shinfo->nr_frags show zero, nr_frags value is zero. Is there anyway we can get data from fragments.

Comment: Please, take a look at `sk_buff` structure. `nr_frags` shows the number of paged fragments, but that's not the only place where the data can be placed in an skb beyond the linear data area. There's also the list of skb fragments attached to this skb at `skb_shinfo(skb)->frag_list` (see `skb_walk_frags()` in the kernel). Perhaps, your data is there. If not, then it's hard to say what's going on without seeing your code on the whole path in the kernel from ingress and up to the call to `sk_data_ready()`.

Comment: @Aleksey data is present at frag_list. thanks for information. i was able to get data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`skb_shinfo(skb)->nr_frags` shows the number of paged fragments, but that's not the only place where data can be placed in an skb beyond the linear data area. There's also the list of skb fragments attached to this skb at `skb_shinfo(skb)->frag_list` (see skb_walk_frags() in the kernel). Your data could be there. If not, then it's hard to say what's going on without seeing your code on the whole path in the kernel from ingress and up to the call to `sk_data_ready()`. It could simply be a bug somewhere.